# Get pandas dataframe where numeric values are not bigger/smaller than 5% of the previous value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, slice

My current solution is the following:

```
    slices = []
    
    for idx in range(0, dataset.size):
        slice = dataset[idx:idx+4]

        if len(slice) < 4:
            break;

        # ---> check = []
        for val in slice[column].values: 
            delta_pos = round(slice[column].iloc[0] * 0.0005, 2)
            delta_neg = round(slice[column].iloc[0] * 0.0005, 2)
            check.append(delta_neg <= round(val, 2) - round(slice[column].iloc[0], 2) <= delta_pos)

        if(all(v == True for v in check)):
            slices.append(slice) # <----
                
    return slices
```

Here, I check each possible four-itemed slice inside the Pandas Dataframe if it meets my requirements. If it does, then slice is added into a separate `slices` array.

But from my opinion, this code is too unreadable. Are there any more reliable and simplier solutions?

---

Here is a small extract of the dataset:

```
VALUE
194.7200000
194.7600000
195.0500000
194.9500000
195.0800000
195.1700000
195.0700000
195.2200000
195.2000000
195.2100000
195.2500000
195.1600000
194.6200000
194.6400000
194.9000000
194.8200000
194.8000000
194.6400000
194.7800000
194.6600000
194.7000000
194.6300000
...
```

Comment: it is, I just wanted the piece of code I want to simplify to become bold

Comment: Ahh, ok. bold does not work inside code environments, I usually add a `# <----` or smth to mark a position :)

Comment: can you share a small example of `dataset` so that we can run the code ourselves?

Comment: how do you want me to share an example? Does dropmefiles service ok for you?

Comment: Just print and share `dataset.iloc[:10, :]` to get the first 10 rows with all the columns

Comment: @HardRock4Life: It is better to edit the question with a data sample. I have just did it for you this time.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `rolling` to create all groups of 4 successive values. To apply the logic you then need to rewrite it as a function that accepts a series (of the 4 values)

```
In [17]: def select_slices(s): 
    ...:     for val in s.values: 
    ...:         delta =  round(s.iloc[0] * 0.0005, 2) 
    ...:         if not (-delta <= round(val, 2) - round(s.iloc[0], 2) <= delta): 
    ...:             return 1 
    ...:     slices.append(s) 
    ...:     return 0 
    ...:                                                                                                                                                                                                           
In [18]: s.rolling(4).apply(select_slices)
```

`rolling` expects a scalar return value therefore the rather unsophisticated `return` statements. I also took the liberty to shorten your code a bit by eleminating duplicate code and returning early.

You can probably get that cleaner by removing the loop and just checking whether the max and min are within your desired range.

On your sample data this gives

```
In [19]: slices                                                                                                                                                                                                    
Out[19]: 
[5    195.17
 6    195.07
 7    195.22
 8    195.20
 dtype: float64,
 7     195.22
 8     195.20
 9     195.21
 10    195.25
 dtype: float64,
 8     195.20
 9     195.21
 10    195.25
 11    195.16
 dtype: float64]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this elegantly in two lines of code using `shift` and some indexing. Say we have a dataframe `df` defined as:

```py
df=pd.DataFrame({'VALUE':{0:194.72, 1:194.76, 2:195.05, 3:194.95, 4:195.08, 5:195.17,
                          6:195.07, 7:195.22, 8:195.2, 9:195.21, 10:195.25,11:195.16,
                          12:194.62,13:194.64,14:194.9,15:194.82,16:194.8,17:194.64,
                          18:194.78,19:194.66,20:194.7,21:194.63}})
```

We can shift the position of all values by one to get the 'previous' value:

```py
df_shifted = df.shift(1, fill_value=df.VALUE[0])
```

And now, we can select values in the original dataframe with a tolerance of 5%:

```py
df_within_5percent = df[abs(df.VALUE - df_shifted.VALUE)< 0.05]
```

That's it! `df_within_5percent` contains the values within 5% tolerance w.r.t. the previous value.

Comment: I humbly believe that it doesn't get any more elegant than this